# What's the fastest way to use Ceph volumes in Docker Swarm?

Tags: docker-swarm, ceph, s3fs

I want to set up a Swarm with persistent and replicated volumes through Ceph. I see these options to combine both services, once both are set up:

1. Configure the host OS to mount a CephFS in `/var/lib/docker/volumes￻`.
2. Use [rexray/rbd](https://rexray.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/schedulers/docker/plug-ins/ceph/#rados-block-device-rbd) as a volume driver.
3. Use [rexray/s3fs](https://rexray.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/schedulers/docker/plug-ins/aws/#simple-storage-service) to access Ceph object store, which is S3-compatible.

I wonder now: which option would deliver fastest performance? Is there another better option that I'm missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In general for best performance you should go for [rbd](https://ceph.com/ceph-storage/block-storage/), since it provides you with direct block access to the ceph volume, whereas s3fs is quite much more machinery to be spun, which eventually result in longer response times. Having quick responses for random read/writes is especially important when you have a scenario like running a postgreSQL (or MariaDB) database with mixed read/write load.

This is only a general advice looking at Ceph rbd. But my guess is this will apply as well to docker storage drivers.